# Ran apt-get clean now I can't boot

Tags: boot, apt, package-management, graphics

This may a bit of a long story, but there were a lot of parts and i'm not sure what exactly caused my problem so please hang in there :)

So i was having trouble with running out of space when trying to install a package (the scipy stack). I found a decent amount of space was in var/cache/apt/archives, so I did a quick search and saw it was fine to remove that with apt-get clean.

I did that and then retried installing, only to still find the error with no space left on disk (disk analyzer said I still had around 600MB so I found that weird), but I went on to work on something else. I modified and tried to compile a c++ file and got an IO error and thought it may be tied to the the space issue. I rebooted hoping that would resolve things and found that the c++ got overwritten somehow. It still existed but it was completely empty. This was devastating in and of itself, but when I tried to open chrome a red minus sign appeared on the top bar saying there was an error with my package dependencies? (sorry i don't remember it exactly) and to run apt-get or open package control and something about a broken '0'?.

I try rebooting yet again and this lead me to my current state. I can't boot properly and am told that my graphics need to be reconfigured? If I boot anyway I get a screen saying

```
cannot write bytes: broken pipe
```

if I select the reconfigure option, it tries to do some battery check and gets hung up.

I tried booting into the console and running apt-get update but i got the error:

```
The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened
```

I apologize for dumping a lot of seemingly meaningless info here, but I'm trying to make sense of what I messed up and providing everything I can.

I am writing this from my windows partition which is thankfully working fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Let me know if there's anything I should provide or try!

EDIT: here is the boot.log

```
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
dosfsck 3.0.12, 29 Oct 2011, FAT32, LFN
There are differences between boot sector and its backup.
Differences: (offset:original/backup)
    65:01/00
    Not automatically fiing this.
\dev\sda6: clean 454978/563040 files, 2134103/2249984 blocks
\dev\sda2: 175 files, 351/62236 clusters
Skipping profile in etc/default/speech-dispatcher
saned disabled: edit /etc/default/saned
```

The kern.log was much more lengthy and harder to figure out but one thing that stuck out was

```
FBDEV(0): FBIOPUTCMAP: Invalid argument
```

I'm gonna try to look into that error further unless someone has some insight.

Comment: A possible fix may be to boot from a Live CD version to recovery your OS.

Comment: What ever happened here, it is unlikely to be caused by clearing the APT cache... Could you check your boot log (`/var/log/boot.log`) and kernel log (`/var/log/kern.log`) for any related errors and add them to your question?

Comment: @the_Seppi I checked the logs and tried deciphering what I could. Edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I researched my error further and found that it was caused by low disk space. (I was somehow at 100% use and 0 bytes free). I was able to enter the console and delete some files and then everything was working as normal.

Comment: Upvoted to encourage self-learning. The question is doomed for a close though.